# javascript remove all objects from array based on property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

How can I remove all objects from an array based on a property value ?

```js
function removeByKey(array, fieldName){
        array.some(function(item, index) {
            return (array[index].name === fieldName) ? !!(array.splice(index, 1)) : false;
        });
        return array;
    }
    
    const myarr = [
      {
        name: 'foo',
        school: 'hoo'
      },{
        name: 'foo',
        school: 'xooo'
      },{
        name: 'bar',
        school: 'xooo'
      }
    ];
    
    console.log(removeByKey(myarr, 'foo'))
```

in the above code, it just removes one of the objects. how can i remove all if matches?

Comment: Change `!!` to `!`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use `filter` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) ?

```
const myarr = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    school: 'hoo'
  },{
    name: 'foo',
    school: 'xooo'
  },{
    name: 'bar',
    school: 'xooo'
  }
];

const filteredArray = myarr.filter(obj => obj.name !== 'foo');
```

Example: https://repl.it/repls/SimultaneousSentimentalForms

Edited to match the comment.

Comment: i mean, i need to REMOVE not keep  the matches.

Comment: ... Then do `obj.name !== 'foo'` .... @storis I edited my answer to match what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter function for this:

```
function removeByKey(arr, propertyValue) {

  return arr.filter(item => item.name !== propertyValue);

}

const myarr = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    school: 'hoo'
  },{
    name: 'foo',
    school: 'xooo'
  },{
    name: 'bar',
    school: 'xooo'
  }
];

console.log(removeByKey(myarr, 'foo'));
```

a bit more generic removeByKey function will be:

```
function removeByKey(arr, propertyName, propertyValue) {

  return arr.filter(item => item[propertyName] !== propertyValue);

}
const myarr = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    school: 'hoo'
  },{
    name: 'foo',
    school: 'xooo'
  },{
    name: 'bar',
    school: 'xooo'
  }
];

console.log(removeByKey(myarr, 'name', 'foo'));
```